# Função debounce retornando várias vezes

Tags: javascript, funções

**Contexto:** É a primeira vez que tento implementar uma função `debounce()` no Javascript e acho que estou esquecendo ou entendi algo errado, porque ela está fazendo várias chamadas na API, apesar de aplicar o `delay`, tenho o seguinte código:

```
async atualizarSelecionarTodosMunicipios(value) {
  const execute = this.debounce(async () => {
    await this.getTotalDaeMunicipio(this.filtroDaeMunicipio);
    await this.gerarGraficoMunicipio();
  }, 1000);
  execute();
},

debounce(func, wait) {
  let timer = null;
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(func, wait);
  };
},
```

A função `atualizarSelecionarTodosMunicipios(value)` é chamada sempre o usuário clica em um checkbox, isso está funcionando, toda vez que clico no checkbox esta função está sendo chamada.

**O problema**: ao clicar no checkbox, a função `atualizarSelecionarTodosMunicipios(value)` é chamada, depois de 1 segundo (1000ms), é feita a chamada na API pela função `execute()` que possui o `debounce`, só que ao clicar várias vezes no checkbox, são feitas várias chamadas na API.

**O que era esperado:** ao clicar várias vezes no checkbox, era para fazer apenas uma chamada na API.

Alguém tem ideia do que estou fazendo errado? Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Recebi uma resposta no Stackoverflow em inglês que me ajudou no problema.

**Resposta:** o problema era que a variável `timer` precisa ser compartilhada entre as funções e não estar no escopo local da função `debounce`, porque ao chamar essa função vária vezes, eram criadas múltiplos `timer`.

**Código atualizado e funcionando:**

```
data() {
  return {
    timer: null,
  }
}

async atualizarSelecionarTodosMunicipios(value) {
  const execute = this.debounce(async () => {
    await this.getTotalDaeMunicipio(this.filtroDaeMunicipio);
    await this.gerarGraficoMunicipio();
  }, 1000);
  execute();
},

debounce(func, wait) {
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.timer = setTimeout(func, wait);
  };
},
```

[Pergunta no Stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158401/debounce-function-returning-multiples-times)